# Azure DevOps Docker build in Pipelines and Docker push in Releases

Tags: c#, .net, azure, docker, azure-devops

We are using build and release Pipelines in Azure DevOps.

I can build and push a Docker container in a build pipeline like this:

```
- task: Docker@2
inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'MyContainerRegistry'
    repository: 'classificationapi'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'src\Services\Classification\ClassificationService.Api\Dockerfile'
    buildContext: ''
```

I have verified in Azure Container registry that it works.

[image]

However I do not want to push the Docker image in every build.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops

I want to push the built Docker image when the release pipeline runs instead.

I can use buildAndPush in Releases like this from an artifact.

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'buildAndPush - classificationapi'
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: MyContainerRegistry
    repository: classificationapi
    Dockerfile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Project/Src-DockerContent/src/Services/Classification/ClassificationService.Api/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Project/Src-DockerContent'
```

This gives an error like this.

> 2022-10-20T17:23:31.0333929Z   Unable to use package assets cache due
> to I/O error. This can occur when the same project is built more than
> once in parallel. Performance may be degraded, but the build result
> will not be impacted. 2022-10-20T17:23:31.3189682Z C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5):
> warning MSB3101: Could not write state file
> "obj\Release\net6.0\Project.Metadata.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache".
> Access to the path
> C:\src\src\Common\Project.Metadata\obj\Release\net6.0\Project.Metadata.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache'
> is denied.
> [C:\src\src\Common\Project.Metadata\Project.Metadata.csproj]
> 2022-10-20T17:23:31.3192917Z C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5):
> warning MSB3101: Could not write state file
> "obj\Release\net6.0\ApiPaging.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache". Access
> to the path
> 'C:\src\src\Helpers\ApiPaging\obj\Release\net6.0\ApiPaging.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache'
> is denied. [C:\src\src\Helpers\ApiPaging\ApiPaging.csproj]
> 2022-10-20T17:23:31.3324719Z C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(190,5):
> error MSB4018: The "GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig" task failed
> unexpectedly. [C:\src\src\Helpers\ApiPaging\ApiPaging.csproj]
> 2022-10-20T17:23:31.3543549Z C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5650,5):
> error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file
> "obj\Release\net6.0\Project.Metadata.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt".
> Access to the path
> 'C:\src\src\Common\Project.Metadata\obj\Release\net6.0\Project.Metadata.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt'
> is denied.
> [C:\src\src\Common\Project.Metadata\Project.Metadata.csproj]
> 2022-10-20T17:23:31.3697424Z   Unable to use package assets cache due
> to I/O error. This can occur when the same project is built more than
> once in parallel. Performance may be degraded, but the build result
> will not be impacted.

However this is not ideal for us either. I would like to use Docker build in our build pipeline and Docker Push when Release pipeline is run. Is this possible?

If I try to do a push only in Releases and try to find the image using Tags `$(Build.BuildId)` (Tags is set both in build and releases) it does not work, as expected.

> 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1790448Z ##[section]Starting: Push -
> classificationapi 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1981638Z
> ============================================================================== 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1982033Z Task         : Docker
> 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1982408Z Description  : Build or push Docker
> images, login or logout, start or stop containers, or run a Docker
> command 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1982789Z Version      : 2.210.0
> 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1983359Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1983731Z Help         :
> https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-tsg 2022-10-25T13:25:28.1984083Z
> ============================================================================== 2022-10-25T13:25:39.2512933Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe
> images 2022-10-25T13:25:39.4268097Z
> [command]C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe push
> ***/classificationapi:4574 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6251803Z REPOSITORY                                   TAG                              IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
> 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6253863Z mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet
> 4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022   df75de263e44   13 days ago   6.04GB 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6255727Z mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
>
> 4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022   93905cba049c   13 days ago   9.34GB 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6256761Z
> mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime
>
> 4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022   a736641c6939   13 days ago   5.7GB 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6257571Z mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
>
> ltsc2022                         06bb218927a8   2 weeks ago   5.26GB
> 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6258377Z mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
>
> ltsc2022                         fc628a662d22   2 weeks ago   297MB
> 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6509177Z The push refers to repository
> [***/classificationapi] 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6510441Z An image does not
> exist locally with the tag: ***/classificationapi
> 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6709669Z ##[error]The process
> 'C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
> 2022-10-25T13:25:56.6790024Z ##[section]Finishing: Push -
> classificationapi

Comment: As I understand you need to run Docker build in build pipeline and Docker Push when Release pipeline is run. Do you have two separate pipeline files(Build and release) in your repo?
May you please share you Pipelines here?

Comment: @AndriyBilous Correct - we use separate pipelines as described here: https://www.patrickkoch.dev/posts/post_03/. The tasks involved are already in the answer above. I think the problem is that the Docker image built is not present on the agent in release since we are using Microsoft-hosted agents for Azure Pipelines.

Comment: I see that in the example all the `tasks` are under the same `step` so there is no problem with accessing build artifacts.
You are right, the problem is that the Docker image in built `step` is not present on the agent in release step.
I can suggest you couple of variants: 1. Use one pipeline with one `step` and two `task` build and push inside it, 2. Push all the images into ACR but tag them differently depends on build source/branch, 3. Use Powershell or Bash step and run Docker commands so you could save Docker image as a file, push it to artifacts and then reuse it in push `step`

Answer (score 1):

### Build

You need to `build` it in the build pipeline, use `docker save` to store it as a tar file, then upload the tar file as a pipeline artifact.

```
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'My registered registry'
        repository: 'repo/image'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/PathTo/Dockerfile'
        buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        tags: |
          dev-latest
          $(Build.BuildNumber)
          $(Build.BuildId)
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Save Docker Image
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          docker save -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/image.tar image:$(Build.BuildNumber)
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/image.tar'
        artifact: 'my-artifact'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

### Release

Then in your release, create a stage with an agent using an agent pool that has access to your registry you want to publish to. Then, add two tasks; a `bash` task to load the saved image tar into the current docker, and then a `docker` task to push it to the registry.

(The yaml output of the release tasks)

```
steps:
- bash: |
   docker load --input $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/_BuildArtifact/my-artifact/image.tar
  displayName: 'Load container from build'
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Push to Regitry'
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'My registered registry'
    repository: 'repo/image'
    command: push
    tags: |
     dev-latest
     $(Build.BuildNumber)
     $(Build.BuildId)
```